# Appending data to dynamic DIVs (created by jquery .clone())

Tags: jquery

I bet I am overlooking something simple here, but I took some time to write this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m9ktD/6/) hoping someone can point out, why its not appending the data from the input to the div `.row` it came from.

**Let's start with the HTML**

```
    //Ill be grabbing HTML from here
    <div id="sample-content">
        <div class="row">
            <button type="button" class="open-editor">open editor</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    //Where the input value will come from, (hidden at start)
    <div class="editor">
        <input name="content" value=""/>
        <button type="button" class="send-to-content">insert content</button>
        <button type="button" class="close-editor">close this editor</button>
    </div>

    //Displaying the actual generated content here. Appending the .row from the sample.
    //Has a button to the editor which I want to append the value to the specific row
    <div class="display-content">

    </div>

    //Add a new row into .display-content
    <button type="button" class="add-row">add row</button>
```

**Then the jQuery**

```
var myApp = {

    openEditor : function(el) {

        jQuery('.editor').addClass('opened')

    },

    closeEditor : function(el) {

        jQuery('.editor').removeClass('opened')

    },

    appendRow : function(el) {

        var cloneRow = jQuery('#sample-content > div.row').clone();

        cloneRow.appendTo('.display-content');

    },

    sendContent : function(el) {

        var contentData = jQuery('input[name="content"]').val();

        alert(contentData +  ' <- append this to the row the button click came from');

        jQuery('.display-content > row').append(contentData);

        myApp.closeEditor()

    },

}

    jQuery('.add-row').on('click', function() {

        myApp.appendRow(this)

    });

    jQuery('.display-content').on('click', '.open-editor', function() {

        myApp.openEditor(this)

    });

    jQuery('.editor').on('click', '.send-to-content', function() {

        myApp.sendContent(this)

    });

    jQuery('.editor').on('click', '.close-editor', function() {

        myApp.closeEditor(this)

    });
```

Everything is from this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9ktD/6/) I made, take a look to get an idea of my angle here.

Essentially user adds a new row, opens an editor and then I want to append the input data to the specific row the open editor came from...

I am not sure how to incorporate `this` when there is two functions occurring and the function to send the data is not the element I am referring to.

If I append content in the first row it appends nicely, then when I add a new row and make a new input value, it appends to the first row and the row it came from, how do I limit it to the row it came from?

I was thinking of possibly needed to create an index function that gets the index of the element, but again not 100% sure how to incorporate it.. Hoping for some tips :)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m9ktD/6/)**

Comment: Wow I forgot a period http://jsfiddle.net/m9ktD/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the row that is currently being edited to `.active`, and append the content to that :

```
var myApp = {
    openEditor : function() {
        $('.editor').addClass('opened');
        $(this).closest('.row').addClass('active');
    },
    closeEditor : function() {
        $('.editor').removeClass('opened');
        $('.row').removeClass('active');
    },
    appendRow : function() {
        var cloneRow = $('#sample-content > div.row').clone();
        cloneRow.appendTo('.display-content');
    },
    sendContent : function() {
        var contentData = $('input[name="content"]').val();
        alert(contentData +  ' <- append this to the row the button click came from');
        $('.row.active').append(contentData);
        myApp.closeEditor();
        $('.row').removeClass('active');
    }
}

$('.add-row').on('click', myApp.appendRow);
$('.display-content').on('click', '.open-editor', myApp.openEditor);
$('.editor').on('click', '.send-to-content', myApp.sendContent);
$('.editor').on('click', '.close-editor', myApp.closeEditor);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/m9ktD/7/)

Comment: "I bet I am overlooking something simple here" I knew I was overlooking something I could have done much more simple..

Answer (score 0):

you written selector wrongly when adding to row class(should be ".row" instead of "row"). inatead of

```
jQuery('.display-content > row').append(contentData);
```

use

```
jQuery('.display-content > .row').append(contentData);
```

Comment: Yeah, I edited that already.. sorry, but still it wasnt 100% fixed I needed to add to the specific element the editor was opened from.